# What is a good way to get a similarity measure of two images that contain a line chart?

Tags: python, opencv, scipy, scikit-learn, scikit-image

I have tried the dHash algorithm which is applied on each image, then a hamming_distance is calculated on both hashes, the lower the number, the higher the similarity.

```
from PIL import Image
import os
import shutil
import glob
from plotData import *

def hamming_distance(s1, s2):
    #Return the Hamming distance between equal-length sequences
    if len(s1) != len(s2):
        raise ValueError("Undefined for sequences of unequal length")
    return sum(ch1 != ch2 for ch1, ch2 in zip(s1, s2))


def dhash(image, hash_size = 8):
    # Grayscale and shrink the image in one step.
    image = image.convert('L').resize(
        (hash_size + 1, hash_size),
        Image.ANTIALIAS,
    )

    pixels = list(image.getdata())

    # Compare adjacent pixels.
    difference = []
    for row in xrange(hash_size):
        for col in xrange(hash_size):
            pixel_left = image.getpixel((col, row))
            pixel_right = image.getpixel((col + 1, row))
            difference.append(pixel_left > pixel_right)

    # Convert the binary array to a hexadecimal string.
    decimal_value = 0
    hex_string = []
    for index, value in enumerate(difference):
        if value:
            decimal_value += 2**(index % 8)
        if (index % 8) == 7:
            hex_string.append(hex(decimal_value)[2:].rjust(2, '0'))
            decimal_value = 0

    return ''.join(hex_string)




orig = Image.open('imageA.png')
modif = Image.open('imageA.png')
hammingDistanceValue = hamming_distance(dhash(orig),dhash(modif))
    print hammingDistanceValue
```

Unfortunately, this approach produces false positives because it does not really look at the line chart shapes as primary similarity feature. I guess, I'd need some kind of machine learning approach maybe from openCV or so. Can anyone guide me into the right direction to something that compares with high precision?

**this is the initial image to compare against a collection of similar images.**

[image]

**this is a *positive* match**
[image]

**this is a *false* match**
[image]

**update:** I added some opencv magic to jme's suggestion below. I try to detect significant features first. Howeve, it still produces false positives, since the overall indicator for similarity is the cummulated value over all features and does not take differences into account that can give a line chart a totally different meaning.

**False Positive example**
[image]

**Example of preprocessed image with significant features marked as red dots**
[image]

```
from PIL import Image
import os
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
import os.path
import shutil
import glob
from plotData import *
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def load_image(path):
    #data = Image.open(path)
    img = cv2.imread(path)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    corners = cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack(gray,25,0.01,10)
    corners = np.int0(corners)

    for i in corners:
        x,y = i.ravel()
        cv2.circle(img,(x,y),3,255,-1)

    return np.mean((255 - np.array(img))**2, axis=2)


symbol = "PBYI"
x = np.arange(1000)

if not os.path.exists('clusters1DSignal/'+symbol+'/'):
    os.mkdir('clusters1DSignal/'+symbol+'/')
else:
    shutil.rmtree('clusters1DSignal/'+symbol+'/')
    os.mkdir('clusters1DSignal/'+symbol+'/')

shutil.copyfile('rendered/'+symbol+'.png', "clusters1DSignal/"+symbol+"/"+symbol+'.png')


img1 = load_image('rendered/'+symbol+'.png')
y1 = np.argmax(img1, axis=0)
f1 = interp1d(np.linspace(0, 1000, len(y1)), y1)
z1 = f1(x)

for filename in glob.iglob('rendered/*.png'):
    try:
        img2 = load_image(filename)
    except:
        continue
    y2 = np.argmax(img2, axis=0)
    f2 = interp1d(np.linspace(0, 1000, len(y2)), y2)
    z2 = f2(x)

    result = np.linalg.norm(z1 - z2)
    if result < 2100:
        print str(result) +": " +filename
        symbolCompare = filename.split("/")[1].replace(".png","")
        shutil.copyfile('rendered/'+symbolCompare+'.png', "clusters1DSignal/"+symbol+"/"+str(result)+"_"+symbolCompare+".png")
```

Comment: If you're able to extract the points you could represent your graph as a 1D signal. Not sure about signal processing, but there might be template matching techniques

Comment: actually I have the points and generate the graphs from there. do you have any tipps with regard to 1D signal matching?

Comment: You can calculate the [correlation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_and_dependence) between the two samples and put a cap on minimum value as the condition that decides whether the two data sets are similar.

Answer (score 1):

The approach I'd take is this: first, convert each image to a 1d signal by finding for each `x` pixel, a representative `y` pixel where the image is red. You can take the mean of the `y` pixels, but for simplicity, I'll just take the first that isn't white:

```
def load_image(path):
    data = Image.open(path)
    return np.mean((255 - np.array(data))**2, axis=2)

img1 = load_image("one.png")
img2 = load_image("two.png")
img3 = load_image("three.png")

y1 = np.argmax(img1, axis=0)
y2 = np.argmax(img2, axis=0)
y3 = np.argmax(img3, axis=0)
```

`y1`, `y2`, and `y3` are 1d arrays which represent the functions in the first, second, and third images. Now we simply treat each array as a vector, and find the `l2` distance between them. We prefer the `l2` distance because the Hamming distance will be somewhat sensitive for this task.

We have a slight problem: the images have different widths, so the `y` arrays aren't of compatible size. A quick-and-dirty fix is to interpolate them to a longer length (we'll use 1000):

```
f1 = interp1d(np.linspace(0, 1000, len(y1)), y1)
f2 = interp1d(np.linspace(0, 1000, len(y2)), y2)
f3 = interp1d(np.linspace(0, 1000, len(y3)), y3)

x = np.arange(1000)
z1 = f1(x)
z2 = f2(x)
z3 = f3(x)
```

Now we can find the distance between the images:

```
>>> np.linalg.norm(z1 - z2)
2608.5368359281415
>>> np.linalg.norm(z1 - z3)
5071.1340610709549
>>> np.linalg.norm(z2 - z2)
5397.379183811714
```

Comment: thanks! I'll try that in a minute and give feedback! I am generating the images from datapoints. what is your opinion... should I just analyse plotted images or somehow process the real data (and how?)

Comment: @Jabb So you have the data that generated these plots? Then by all means, use that! Just apply the same approach: represent each function as a vector in some space, and use the distance between vectors as the distance between functions.

Comment: yes I do. Will need to open up another SO question. Unfortunately, my math skills are not that good. But thanks for pointing me to a better direction.

Comment: Hi jme, I tried your suggestion. I think a different approach is needed. My initial and your approach compare the images by their "cumulated" most common features. This works in many cases, but sometimes it doesn't for example when a graph is similar in 99% but in 1%, there is a significant peak that gives the graph a totally different meaning. I thought, it might be better then to detect some significant features first and then apply you approach, but it didn't really help. (see my updated answer). Maybe you have another idea?

Comment: @Jabb How are you determining whether two images are similar? You have to choose a threshold, and the best way to do this is to look at the data and pick the threshold which minimizes the error (actually, pick a threshold which minimizes the error on a *validation* set). An alternative to the `l2` distance is the `l-infinity` distance: `np.max(np.abs(x - y))`. In other words, it's the maximum vertical gap between the two graphs.