# How to precisely generate a similarity measure between line charts with similar features

Tags: python, opencv, pandas, scipy, scikit-learn

I am trying to compare one line chart to a number of other line charts and I would like to find all charts that are similar with regard to their significant markers' positions.

[image]

I already tried a few solutions that involve correlating the graphs and then getting a distance measure (cost of total similarity between two charts). So the lower the measure, the higher the similarity.

[Other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27571511/what-is-a-good-way-to-get-a-similarity-measure-of-two-images-that-contain-a-grap)

The above works quite good but not in all cases. For example, if two charts share 90% percent of features but there is 10% of the features such as strong peaks. Then those two charts are not really similar.

Currently, I am normalizing each graph and then I use a Shi-Tomasi Corner Detector to mark interesting signal points in each graph.

Is there a different approach, that can take "significant" peaks into account?

As requested!

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: You want significant peaks to be considered as wrong measures or you want then to be a real insimilarity? Try Hausdorff-distance!

Comment: given two charts A and B with a peak in each chart (each peak at the same position), it should be considered as a similarity. In opposition given two charts A and B, where A is similar to B in all aspects, except for the peak, similarity should be lower.

Comment: Did you try sum of squared distances etc?

Comment: nope. Can you elaborate on squared distances?

Comment: Do I understand correctly from your other question that you draw charts in order to programmatically compare data points you already have ? If so, I believe you would be much better off finding a model to which you can fit your curves ([Approximation Theory on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximation_theory)) and then compare those approximations. The kind of model you should use is much dependent on the nature of your data.

Comment: Oh and if you can't make any assumption on the data, I guess the correlation approach is the way to go.

Comment: Could you share images for 4 graphs? I would like to test something.

Comment: Hi karlphillip. As requested! Thanks!!